# How can I control the order of attributes in my xml serialization?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Is there a way to have the System.Xml.Serialization serialize attributes in a specific order?  I am creating  new xml export and the attributes are not in the same order currently.  I know that attribute order should not matter, but I have to send this xml to servers that may not have such enlightened ideas.

Comment: I don't think so.  With an element you can specify an Order but not with an attribute.

Comment: Depending on how you have to deliver your xml data to these fantastic servers there's always xslt to produce the desired xml structure.